# What happens when the client of webservice goes down - while the webservice is doing processing

Tags: .net, web-services

Condition:

```
 1. Client application (windows) sends a message to a webservice
 2. Webservice is does some processing
 3. Client application exists no more - loses it's state or deleted or down
 4. Webservice finishes processing and returns a value
```

What happens. Does the webservice throw an exception?

Answer (score 1):

The Server would send the data into the nowhere.. The Server would not really recognize that the client has died and complete it's processing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it may through an exception, but not in your Web Service code. For this you will have to watch for an event in Global.asax, Error event, here you can log event to any log files for reviewing later.

There is also an api to see if client is connected or not, HttpContext.Current.Response.IsClientConnected or something similar, it used to be there in the past,I havent checked lately, but watching for error event in Global.asax should help you.